# Full Calendar: How to create an event with a duration of more than 24 hours?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar and when I set the calendar view to ***Week View*** and try to create an event with a duration greater than 1 day, the event's start time label is changed to ***0:00*** and won't update. I have tried to increase the maxTime to more than 24 hours as follows (Which did not help):

```
fcViews.agenda = {
'class': AgendaView,
defaults: {
    allDaySlot: true,
    allDayText: 'all-day',
    slotDuration: '00:30:00',
    minTime: '00:00:00',
    maxTime: '48:00:00',
    slotEventOverlap: true // a bad name. confused with overlap/constraint system
}
```

};

I tried to do the same on the calendar at FullCalendar's official webpage and it has the same behavior. Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namaste @Arvindji

Calendar timeline should not be greater than 1 day. You should restrict max time to 24:00:00

```
maxTime: '24:00:00',
```

Because if you set maxTime: '48:00:00', then fullcalendar will show 48 hours in one day as a result each day column in fullcalendar will have 48 hours. Here there is a loophole in timeline. But the event will not show properly.
So try to bind 24 hours as max time and see result, calendar will break events sharing two days into two parts for both days separately.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: as an alternative, you can use minTime: '04:00:00', maxTime: '28:00:00' - if you want to offset the day, seems to work fine